# Unable to run selenium webdriver script using TestNG

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I have integrated eclipse & TestNG & could able to run one sample Java program which provides the output folder. But while included web driver script it could not run using TestNG, but able to run the same using Java program(two choices it ask while right click on the script to run).

Please le me know where the issue might be.

Thanks,
Amal

Comment: Need to give the testng annotation.

Comment: Share the testng code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chetan said in the comments - you need to attach the `@Test` annotation to your method.

your method would look something like...

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
  WebDriver driver = new...
}
```

Also when you import, import TestNG's Test annotation. **not** jUnit's.